# Will reseting my 2011 Macbook Pro bring it back to the old version?

Tags: macbook-pro

Hi will resetting my 2011 Macbook Pro bring it back to the old version? I'm asking because i wish to run my pro tools but El Captian is considered "too advanced" for my software. Trying to save money and possibly reset my Mac. Does anyone know the answer to this? Thanks!

Comment: What version do you want to go back to?

Comment: Are you reinstalling from a backup or from the recovery utility?

Comment: I not really quite sure, but when i try to start my pro tools it says that I need 10.6 or higher. I'm currently using 10.11 El Capitan. So right now i'll say 10.6 which ever version that is.

Comment: and fbara I really haven't made a decision on how to reinstall yet because I don't know which reinstallation procedure will help me best to get my software working

Comment: Is your Mac an early or late 2011 model? From the menu bar can you select "About this Mac" and read what is shown?

Comment: Hey Dave thanks for commenting, but my Macbook is late 2011

Answer (score 1):

If you Mac was shipped with OS X 10.6 or earlier, then the Mac came with an installation DVD. If your Mac was shipped with OS X 10.7 or later, then you can download that version from the internet. You will need to boot your Mac using [Internet Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and download the original shipped OS X version.

> Early 2011 MacBook Pro models shipped with OS X 10.6 and the late 2011 MacBook Pro models came with OS X 10.7 installed.

Snow Leopard OS 10.6 is now to old to be of any use for accessing the internet or running most current applications. OS X 10.7 is better, but not by much. Your best bet is to see what previous purchased versions of OS X are still available from the Apple Store. I believe, Yosemite OS X 10.10 can not be downloaded even if you previous purchased this version.

It is generally a good idea to backup any version of OS X you download, before installing or upgrading your operating system. What I mean by this is that you backup the .dmg file you downloaded. What people are learning is that you can not rely on Apple to allow you to download a previously purchased OS X version at a later date.

If you can download Mavericks OS X 10.9 or later, you can copy the installation files to a flash drive. You can boot from the flash drive and perform a clean install of OS X. The instruction are given at the web site [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).